# How to draw a line in JavaFX with the mouse?

Tags: javafx, line, draw, paint

I am working on a paint program in which a button is clicked that toggles the button that draws lines. My code doesn't do what I want it to and instead draws a strange fan shape whenever I try to draw multiple lines. I want it to be able to draw multiple straight lines with the mouse.

````
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                initialTouch = new Pair<>(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
        });

        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                gc.strokeLine(initialTouch.getKey(), initialTouch.getValue(), event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
        });

        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            }
        });

    }```

That method is called when a button is pushed to draw the line. I am expecting multiple lines, but I stead get a fan shape.
````

Answer (score 0):

What you do, is:

You create start Point. 
And then for each DRAG movement you create a OWN line from the Start location to the new Location. Hence you create a lot of lines that resemble a shape.

**What you want is**:

Create a start point and than draw to the end Point. 
So you should ONLY draw a line to the Graphical Context when the Mouse released.

just Move what you do in "dragged" to the "released" part and it sould work.

When you want "Preview" you should Use a Line Object and add it to the View, and then when release the mouse you should delete the Object it.